# Moving repeated characters in string to the end

Tags: c, c-strings

I tried to move the repeated characters in a string to its end positions but my code not working for more than two repeated characters. I tried to solve it but not getting it.
Here is my code

```
main () {
char string[100];
char *s, *p;
char c;
scanf("%s", string);
s = string;
c = *s++;
while (*s){
    if(*s == c){
        for(p = s; *p ; p++)
            *p = *(p + 1);
        *--p = c;
    }
    c = *s;
    s++;
}
printf ( "%s\n", string);
}
```

Comment: I entered 100 characters and it crashed. :(

Comment: @Daniel I think its not crash.

Comment: read http://sscce.org and improve the question to include expected output and observed output, or in case of crash the line (in the question code) where it crashes (use debugger), or in case of compiler error, the error and line (in the question code) where it happens.

Comment: Do you need the second and subsequent occurrence of each character that appears more than once at the end, or just adjacent repeated characters?  Do you know how long your strings are going to be?  An answer that's suitable for short strings (say less than 100 bytes) may not be suitable for long strings.

Comment: Also, please fix the indentation (SO code formatting is tricky with *tabs*, better use only spaces). Also having descriptive variable names would make it more likely for people to bother looking at the code. Additionally, avoid using `++` and `--` inside expressions like `*--p = c;` until you are very fluent with C, it's too easy to make mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I will keep them in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you like the test code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void rep2end(char *string) {
char *s, *p, *e, *stop;
char c;
s = string;
e = s+strlen(string)-1; /* find end of string */
stop = e;               /* place to stop processing */
while (stop > s){        
    c = *s;             /* char to look for */
    while(*(s+1) == c){ /* repeated char */
        for(p = s+1; *p ; p++){ /* shuffle left to overwrite current pos *s */
            *(p-1) = *p;
        }
        *e = c; /* set end char to be the repeat we just found */
        stop--; /* bump the stop position left to prevent reprocessing */
    }
    s++;
    }
}


main () {
char *in[]={"aabbccefghi", "uglyfruit", "highbbbbchair"};
char *out[]={"abcefghiabc", "uglyfruit", "highbchairbbb"};
char string[100];
int i;

for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
strcpy(string, in[i]);
rep2end(string);
if (!strcmp(string,out[i])) { 
   printf("ok\n");
   }else {
   printf("fail %s should be %s\n", string, out[i]);
   }


}
return 0;
}
```